# Cambiar el estado de activo a inactivo o viceversa en php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery

necesito que el estado (en este caso curso-paralelo) se cambie de activo a inactivo o viceversa con solo darle click donde dice activo o inactivo, sin la necesidad de estar abriendo otro formulario para modificarlo ya que eso si tengo pero me dijeron que así no :(
De antemano gracias por su ayuda

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>
    <section id="container">
        <h1 class="Titulo_lista"><i class='fas fa-list'> Lista de asignacion de curso a paralelo</i></h1>
        <form action="" method="get" class="form_search">
        </form> 
        <table><thead>
            <tr >
                <th><i class="fa fa-chain"></i>  Codigo</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-university"></i>  Curso</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-university"></i>  Paralelo</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i>  Estado</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>  Acciones</th>
            <?php      
      $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT cp.id_cp, cp.id_curso, cp.id_paralelo, cp.estado_cp, c.id_curso, c.descrip_curso, p.id_paralelo, p.descrip_paralelo
                                           from curso_paralelo cp
                                           INNER JOIN curso c ON cp.id_curso = c.id_curso
                                           JOIN paralelo p ON cp.id_paralelo = p.id_paralelo
                                           ORDER BY descrip_curso ASC LIMIT $desde,$por_pagina ");
        mysqli_close($connection);
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if ($result > 0) {
            while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            ?><tr>
                <td><?php echo $data['id_cp']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['descrip_curso']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['descrip_paralelo']; ?></td>
                <td><?php
        if($data['estado_cp'] == '1'){
            echo '<span class="activo">Activo</span>';
            }
        else if ($data['estado_cp'] == '2') {
            echo '<span class="desactivo">Desactivo</span>';
        }?></td>
                <td>
                <a class="link_delete borrar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteAsignacionCP<?php echo $data['id_cp']; ?>"href="#"><i class='fas fa-trash'></i> </a>              
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php    
                    }
                }       
        ?>  </tbody>
        </table>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deberias intentarlo con ajax (javascript) y que este llame a un archivo PHP que se comunicará con la base de datos y realizara el UPDATE de ese valor cada vez que se cambie el estado.  Así no tendrias que recargar la pagina. En caso contrario deberás usar un `<form>` con un boton `submit` y con los inputs y datos necesarios para que al pulsar el boton los envie al archivo PHP que modificara los datos y a su vez te devolvera de nuevo la pagina con el cambio (es más aparatoso porque lo recarga todo pero tambien es factible). Cuando lo tengas preparado nos lo enseñas y te ayudamos si podemos.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Hacer un archivo PHP que acepte una variable GET (dentro de la url) con el id del elemento a modificar, haga el cambio y te redireccione a esta página. Para llegar el bóton de "activar" será un link a ese archivo - tendrás que generar la url dinamicamente con el id.
2. Crear un WS en PHP que haga el cambio recibiendo la variable por GET o POST, y podrás llamar al servicio utilizando AJAX. La forma más fácil de llamarlo es usando $.ajax con jquery, pero no es la única (ni la mejor... posiblemente).

[image: Opción AJAX]

**Docs**: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**EasyDocs**: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

### A saber...

La primera opción es fácil de implementar, pero te da un mal UX.

La segunda opción es más limpia y te dará un mejor UX, pero por otro lado involucra JS.

**Comentario**: En un ambiente empresarial deberías tener un arquitecto de software que debe definir eso.

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia... ¿que es un WS?

Comment: Un webservice.. básicamente es un programa PHP (en este caso) que recibe variables por el protocolo HTTP y devuelve una respuesta.

Comment: Vale, vale, no tenia muy claro a lo que te referias, luego lo he buscado y visto en la wikipedia y algunos ejemplos por ahi... Llevo haciendolo toda la vida y nos sabia que se llamaba asi :-)  Para mi siempre ha sido simplemente una llamada a un archivo PHP con parametros que devuelve texto en diversos formatos segun se tercie. Gracias por la aclaración.